# Set new field priority in SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of bills with the following structure:

```
id | store_name | sum | payment_date
1  | Amazon     | 10  | 11.05.2022
2  | Amazon     | 20  | 11.05.2022
3  | Ebay       | 15  | 11.05.2022
4  | AppleStore | 13  | 11.05.2022
5  | Google Play| 6   | 11.05.2022
```

What I need is to select all data from table and set additional field "Priority" based on a sum of bill. First 2 rows get priority 1, next 2 rows get priority 2, others get 0:

```
id | store_name | sum | payment_date | priority
2  | Amazon     | 20  | 11.05.2022   | 1
3  | Ebay       | 15  | 11.05.2022   | 1
4  | AppleStore | 13  | 11.05.2022   | 2
1  | Amazon     | 10  | 11.05.2022   | 2
5  | Google Play| 6   | 11.05.2022   | 0
```

In addition table contains data about bills from various days (field payment_date) and this priority should be set based on data inside each single day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the rows for each day and then assign priority based on the row number:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(payment_date) ORDER BY sum DESC)
       WHEN 1 THEN 1
       WHEN 2 THEN 1
       WHEN 3 THEN 2
       WHEN 4 THEN 2
       ELSE 0
       END AS priority
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, store_name, sum, payment_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Amazon',      10, DATE '2022-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Amazon',      20, DATE '2022-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Ebay',        15, DATE '2022-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Apple Store', 13, DATE '2022-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Google Play',  6, DATE '2022-05-11' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | STORE_NAME | SUM | PAYMENT_DATE | PRIORITY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | Amazon | 20 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 3 | Ebay | 15 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 4 | Apple Store | 13 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 1 | Amazon | 10 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 5 | Google Play | 6 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=082ea3b6fcc4b99cbe9d98bb7fdb6b3c)*

Comment: Can I do this somehow using FETCH NEXT N ROWS? Or only with rownum?
And I need such priority field based on a payment_date field. For example for 10.05 i'll have another priority 1,2,0 rows

Comment: @Evillain While it is theoretically possible that you might be able to solve it using `FETCH NEXT n ROWS` or `ROWNUM` it will almost certainly be less efficient than using an analytic function (especially since you want to calculate the `priority` for each day).

Comment: And if I want not strict case when 1 then 1, for example: first 20 rows mark with priority 1. Can it be done without inner select?

Comment: @Evillain A nested sub-query is not an evil thing as you would only be using it to filter and would not be querying any additional tables. That said, yes, just use `WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ... WHEN 20 THEN 1 WHEN 21 THEN 2 ...` or `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) <= 20 THEN 1 WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) <= 40 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END` or use the `DECODE` function.